# Repenting when sun rises from the west

Tags: jannah, tawba, death, jahannam, day-of-judgement

Hi so im a revert and I just read that you can’t repent once the sun rises from the west. But I’m wondering, does that mean that if we commit sins after that we can’t repent? Or does that just mean the disbelievers? What would happen if I accidentally commit shirk/kufr after that sign, can I not ask for forgiveness anymore? I don’t know how to interpret it and it really scares me now.

Comment: Please consider adding a source of your claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I'm so happy for you actually! Very glad you were able to stumble upon the truth and I ask The Lord, Allah The All Mighty to keep you steadfast on your deen! With regards to the sun rising from the west, that's one of the last signs of the hour (judgment day); which a lot of the signs has already happened actually. And yes, once the sun rises from the west, the doors of repentance are closed for good, and no amount of belief will save you if you were a non-believer (non-Muslim) prior to that incident, as it's too late at that point.

But there's no need to be stressed over it or feel scared! All Praise be to Allah, the religion is very easy and simple and Allah said in His Wise Book:

> "Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. ..." Quran [2: 286]

> "... Allah puts no burden on any person beyond what He has given him. After a difficulty, Allah will soon grant relief." Quran [65: 7]

And no need to have these insinuations, have the strongest trust in Allah Subhanahu' Wa Ta'la and remember that Our Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah says: 'I am just as My slave thinks I am, (i.e. I am able to do for him what he thinks I can do for him) and I am with him if He remembers Me. ... [Sahih al-Bukhari 7405]

Comment: Thank you, but I still have one more question: do your good/bad deeds after that count? Because people would still sin but since you can’t repent I was wondering that

Comment: @dlsj I believe that all actions will be dismissed from that point onwards, as the Hadith narrates that once this incident takes place; ```everyone``` will become a believer (in Allah), because everyone will see it with their own naked eyes and the ultimate truth has prevailed. Check the Hadith: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6506